# constant variable in base class

Tags: c++, abstract-class, derived-class

I have two classes, `Abstract` and `Base`. `Abstract` is the base of the `Base` class.

```
class Abstract 
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract();

    const int                   aID;

protected:
    // Constructor is protected because this class is abstract.
    Abstract(int xID) : 
    aID(xID){}
};

#define BASE_CLASS_ID           0x0001

class Base : public Abstract
{
public:
    Base() : 
    Abstract(BASE_CLASS_ID){} // change the ID
};
```

Now for any `Derived` class for this base class, I want the same ID `BASE_CLASS_ID` to be used.
How can I require all my derived classes to employ this behavior?

Comment: You've already done it!

Comment: btw, Derived will call Base::Base(), but not Abstract::Abstract()

Comment: Can you explain to me how? I don't think Derived automatically calls the Base constructor though, or does it?

Comment: Any class that inherits `Base` must call `Base`'s constructor (in this case is not needed because `Base::base()` has no parameters so it gets called automatically. `Base`'s constructor already calls `Abstract`'s constructor using `BASE_CLASS_ID`.

Comment: I'm assuming you are declaring `class Derived : public Base`, is that correct?

Comment: It's better to have pure virtual destructor to make class abstract, rather than protected constructor

Answer (score 0):

If you want that all derived classes would have the same value of constant data member aID why will not you define this data member as a static constant data member? For example

```
class Abstract 
{
public:
    virtual ~Abstract();
    enum  { BASE_CLASS_ID = 0x0001 };
    const static int aID = BASE_CLASS_ID;

protected:
    // Constructor is protected because this class is abstract.
    Abstract() = default;
};
```